# Compizconfig needs rebind on every startup

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, compiz

I bind the expose function to my top-right and bottom-left corners. It works well. However, if I reboot my pc, it won't be binded anymore. In the compizconfig settings, it's still binded, but I need to remove the bind and rebind - and it works again. Needless to say, every annoying.

Any fixes out there?

Comment: what do you mean by `expose function`? please name which plugin instead & I'll give you a possible workaround.

Comment: @doug In compizconfig, it's the "scale" option under windows management, bindinds-> Initiate picker for all windows. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround -

Set up compiz as you wish, then in ccsm go > Preferences > Plugin List

From there disable "Automatic plugin sorting" > in right side column (enabled plugins),  highlight `scale` & click on the `Down` button until it's below the `unityshell` plugin (usually the last listed

Then close ccsm leaving auto plugin sorting disabled. If making any changes in the future 1st re-enable auto plugin sorting, make changes then disable, ect.

2nd alt. workaround, don't do above one

Use a start up script to reset the binding. This could be done thru an autostart .desktop that is set for a small delay of a couple of sec.

One example of window picker all to bottom right

In ~/.config/autostart create a desktop file, named scale1.desktop here to test.

(- or create via cli -

`mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart`

`gedit ~/.config/autostart/scale1.desktop`

Insert, (copy & paste best way) this inside, the Exec= line has a command to set the binding, the delay line is set to 3 sec if need be it can be adjusted. Note that the command can also be run from a terminal to test, ect. Also note that the Exec= is one line if it appears differently in this post so do c&p rather than type, To show that,  the  command is

`dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-all-edge "'BottomRight'"`

So c&p this into the newly created .desktop file

`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Set scale binding1
Exec=dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-all-edge "'BottomRight'"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=3`

Would look like this in gedit

[image: scale1.desktop]

A 3rd way would be to change the default bindings  of None for these actions  to what you want, however that's a bit involved & not suitable for here, ubuntu forums better for that.

Comment: Alternative 1 does not work. It makes Ubuntu log out so I need to type my password again? That's weird. I'm unsure of how to approach alternative 2?

Comment: Not sure why you can't use ccsm as described, makes no sense. Anyway for 2 start by opening a terminal then copy & paste the 2 commands under `or create via cli` into terminal 1 at a time, press enter to execute. This will open gedit with a blank file. In that file copy & paste all of the above under `So c&p this into the newly created .desktop file` , then save the file & exit gedit. If you don't still get this then please start a thread in ubuntu forums > Desktop Environments. (- it's so much easier than the limitations here..

Comment: I tried using Unity Tweak tool as it could do the same as  CompizConfig.... Yet, the same problem remains. It resets every time i reboot?

What could be the problem since it's not confined to compiz? hmm?

Comment: I messed up something in dconf. Now, every time I hit the top-right corner(hot corner), it simply blackscreens and takes me back to the login process of Ubuntu?

This is weird..

Comment: Open ccsm > Preferences > Plugin List & enable  Automatic plugin sorting if you have it disabled. Then open  Scale > Bindings & set all the edge ones (monitor icon) back to defaults by clicking on the little x icon button on far right.   Then I don't know, gave you 2 simple methods that didn't involve tweak tool or anything else.

Comment: Can you point me towards resetting all hot corner etc. binds and start over? Both from compiz and Ubuntu tweak tool? I purged them but binds still active and crashes my system(throws me to login screen) After doing this, I'll try your method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, maybe you should get rid of tweak. If last comment has no effect then open a terminal, run this command `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` then follow with this one which should log you out. `setsid unity` when logging back in you should be at the shipped defaults for compiz/unity. Use copy & paste on these 2 commands

Comment: Welp now I have no desktop, only the wallpaper shows. This gets worse and worse hahaha. How do I wipe everything from the settings and get just the standard unity layout with everything at default? Essentially nothing works now, I can only run terminal through alt+ctrl+f3 and the commands you posted do not work.